# How to disable facebook iframe page plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have embedded a facebook iframe in my site and I want to disable it when the screen reaches a certain width. I don't know how to actually make the iframe go away. Here's my implementation:

```
window.onresize = () => {
                    if (window.innerWidth <= 1200) {
                        document.getElementsByClassName("fb-page")[0].setAttribute("data-height", "0");
         
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementsByClassName("fb-page")[0].setAttribute("data-height", "130");
                    }
```

But it doesn't work because the min height is 70 and the iframe itself doesn't refresh. Any ideas?

Comment: you can simply use CSS media queries

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you you try this using CSS:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { // or other width
    iframe {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Or you can use `height: 0` instead of `display` if there are no paddings.